# Linq to XML query nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have been working on this for two days and I don't know why it doesn't work.  I have the following XML

```
Data = new XDocument(
             new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
             new XComment("UserData"),
             new XElement("Users",
                 new XElement("user",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Bugs Bunny"),
                        new XAttribute("userID", "bbunny"),
                        new XAttribute("usertype", "Customer"),
                            new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "checking"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 1000),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "1/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "1/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 1000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 1000)))),

                new XElement("user",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Tasmanian Devil"),
                        new XAttribute("userID", "tdevil"),
                        new XAttribute("usertype", "Customer"),
                            new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "checking"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", -20),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "1/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 1000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 1000)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "2/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 900),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "withdrawal"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 100)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 120),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "withdrawal"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", -20)))),

                new XElement("user",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Sam Sheepdog"),
                        new XAttribute("userID", "ssheepdog"),
                        new XAttribute("usertype", "Customer"),
                        new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "checking"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 1000),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "1/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 1000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 1000)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "2/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 500),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "transfer"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 500)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 500),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 1000))),
                       new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "savings"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 500),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 500),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 500)))),


                 new XElement("user",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Elmer J. Fudd"),
                        new XAttribute("userID", "efudd"),
                        new XAttribute("usertype", "Customer"),
                        new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "checking"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 100000),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "1/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 100000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 100000)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "2/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 50000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "transfer"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 50000)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 50000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 100000))),
                       new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "moneymarket"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 50000),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 50000),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 50000)))),

                     new XElement("user",
                        new XAttribute("name", "Ralph Wolf"),
                        new XAttribute("userID", "rwolf"),
                        new XAttribute("usertype", "Customer"),
                        new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "checking"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 200),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "4/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "1/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 100),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 100)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "4/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 100),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 100))),
                       new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "savings"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 1000),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "4/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "3/1/2013"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 400),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 400)),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "4/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 600),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 1000))),
                       new XElement("account",
                                new XAttribute("accounttype", "moneymarket"),
                                new XAttribute("actbal", 500),
                                new XAttribute("actbaldate", "5/1/2013"),
                                    new XElement("trans",
                                        new XAttribute("tranDate", "5/1/2012"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranAmount", 500),
                                        new XAttribute("trantype", "deposit"),
                                        new XAttribute("tranBalance", 500)))),
                                        ));
```

I don't understand why this won't give me a list of trans for a provided userID == efudd and accounttype = checking.  When I call foreach it startsto iterate over the items, But then it just stops and there is nothing found.

```
IEnumerable<Transaction> userAcctInfo = 
    from item in Data.Descendants("user")
    where (string)item.Attribute("usertype") == "Customer" &&
         (string)item.Attribute("userID") == userID
    from accts in item.Descendants("account")
    where (string)accts.Attribute("accounttype") == account
    from trans in item.Descendants("user").Descendants("account").Descendants("trans")
    select new Transaction((DateTime)trans.Attribute("tranDate"),
                            (string)trans.Attribute("trantype"),
                            (decimal)trans.Attribute("tranAmount"),
                            (decimal)trans.Attribute("transBalance"));
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have looked at several examples here and i just don't understand.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to add `Root` property call (or `Element("Users")`) at the beginning of the query.
2. You should use `Elements` instead of `Descendants` when you know where exactly the element is in tree structure.
3. Why did you start querying for `trans` from the `item` instead of `accts`, which is already defined there?

That one works and returns 3 items

```
var userAcctInfo =
    from item in Data.Root.Elements("user")
    where (string)item.Attribute("usertype") == "Customer" &&
          (string)item.Attribute("userID") == userId
    from accts in item.Elements("account")
    where (string)accts.Attribute("accounttype") == account
    from trans in accts.Elements("trans")
    select new Transaction((DateTime)trans.Attribute("tranDate"),
                           (string)trans.Attribute("trantype"),
                           (decimal)trans.Attribute("tranAmount"),
                           (decimal)trans.Attribute("tranBalance"));
```

Comment: THANKS! To answer your question, I was just playing around with the code when I couldn't get what I wanted.  I just started using linq this week so when I had the query with accts and it didn't work i thought maybe I misunderstood what I was supposed to do based on the samples I have found poking around on the web, so I was changing it around.  Good to know that my original thought was correct I just needed a better understanding.  I did not know what the difference uses for Descendants and Elements nor about the root element... Is there a good beginner book or reference you can recommend?